# Redirecting non www to www ONLY for domain, subdomain without www

Tags: multisite

How to set htaccess to such examples in a Wordpress Multisite:

- domain.com - redirect to - www.domain.com
- sudomain.domain.com - no redirect

I have a `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)` when my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to ask explicit for `%{HTTP_HOST}` to be `domain.com`. All implicit conditions like »does `%{HTTP_HOST}` NOT start with `www`« will effect all subdomains too. So this should work for your case

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure, that the constant `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and the domain attribute (in network settings) of your root blog is set to `www.domain.com`. The `NOBLOGREDIRECT` constant might also be helpful for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any codes in htaccess file. There is very easy solution to this. In the 'Network Admin -> Settings -> Domains' page, add both the www. and non-www. versions of the domain, select the box of 'primary' for if you want to mainly use for www. or non-www. and both will be assigned to the website.

Comment: `Network Admin -> Settings -> Domains` hasn't existed for a long time and does not exist in current versions of WP